# Loading sub reports in main reports in java jasper netbeans

Tags: java, subreport

I want to load sub reports 14th1 to the main report 15th.. but through this code i am getting errors.. can anyone help me out through this code?
but when i dont attach sub reports it works fine with this code.

```
JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\Neetesh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\labproject\\src\\13th.jrxml");  

String sql="select main_test, sub_test, item, patient_id, normal_value, unit, results, remarks, date_v from tbl_report where patient_id='"+Patients+"' order by main_test ";
JRDesignQuery newQuery = new  JRDesignQuery();
newQuery.setText(sql);
jd.setQuery(newQuery);
JasperDesign sub = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\Neetesh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\labproject\\src\\14th1.jrxml");
           Map para=new HashMap();
        para.put("Sub1", sub);

JasperReport jr=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got a similar issue. What I did was that, I previewed the sub report in Jasper iReport Designer. After that i run the code and it worked fine.

I believe when we preview the report it is compiled correctly and works for us through java code.

Whereas without previewing when we try to run it from the code, the code is not able to compile it at runtime.

That is the code only loads a precompiled report successfully.

See if this works for you. Thanks.

Comment: didnt find the solution. didnt work that way. can you help me with some more suggestions?

Comment: i compiled the report and previewed it , it worked fine. my question is when i run the program through the java code the sub report  didn't appear. But when i remove the sub report the java programs works fine.

Comment: Quite strange. I can look at it if all code is with me. Otherwise its difficult for me to tell. But I am not sure if you can share all code with me.

Comment: would be great if you could help.